# Data Loss in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, data-loss

I have a VM running on Azure and I have a CRM system running on this VM. For some reason, all the data entered in the CRM got lost and the person who set up the VM did not enable backup. So I can't restore to the last instance as well.

I don't know what exactly happened. I can't find Azure support to get on a call with them to check if any of the data is recoverable.

Please anyone guide me on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very big chance the data that got lost was stored on the VM's temporary disk:

> **Temporary disk** - Temporary disks use a solid-state drive that is located on the same Azure host as the VM. Temp disks are highly performant and may be used for operations such as temporary data processing. However, if the VM is moved to a new host, any data stored on a temporary disk is removed. The size of the temporary disk is determined by the VM size. Temporary disks are assigned a drive letter of D: by default.

Source: [Default Azure Disks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-manage-data-disk#default-azure-disks)

Unfortunately any data lost from the temporary disk is not recoverable.